# dual norm of norm 2

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems

So given a norm $\|\cdot\|$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the dual norm is defined as
$$ \|x\|^* := \sup_{\|u\|=1}u^Tx.$$

I am wondering what happens in the case of norm 2, ie, $\|x\|_2 := x^Tx$, does it hold that $\|\cdot\|_2^*$ is the norm 2 itself? You know... Similar to the $l^p$ spaces in functional analisys? Or does it not hold?

Comment: It holds, look at the Wikipedia article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm.

Comment: It is exactly a special case of the $\ell^p$ norms in functional analysis so the same thing is true for the same reason.